# How to create one or more options within JSON schema with objects?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Sorry if this has been posted before! I couldn't find an answer that fit my use case and worked :(

I have the following JSON (**JSON 1**) and I was writing up a JSON schema *(see at the end)* for it. Everything for the most part works except for right where we have prop5 and objects inside it.

**JSON 1**

```
  "prop1": "somestuff",
  "prop2": "morestuff",
  "temp_list": [
    "stuff",
    "otherstuff",
    "final stuff"
  ],
  "prop4": "morestuff",
  "prop5": {
    "sub_prop_1": {
      "more_properties": "temp",
      "and_even_more": "temp"
    }
  },
  "prop6": "finallyDone"
}
```

I want to create an option where I can have one or more of the three "sub props" like in **JSON 2**.

**JSON 2**

```
{
  "prop1": "somestuff",
  "prop2": "morestuff",
  "temp_list": [
    "stuff",
    "otherstuff",
    "final stuff"
  ],
  "prop4": "morestuff",
  "prop5": {
    "sub_prop_1": {
      "more_properties": "temp",
      "and_even_more": "temp"
    },
    "sub_prop_2": {
      "randomProp": "stuff", 
      "anotherOne": "moreStuff"
    }, 
    "sub_prop_3": {
      "last_random_prop": "somestuff"
    }
  },
  "prop6": "finallyDone"
}
```

Both JSON's should be valid.

However, I don't think I'm writing the schema up correctly. The current behavior accepts any property that may be listed under "prop 5" regardless of name and type of values are input in the "sub props".

The expected behavior is I have either one or more of three "sub_props" and whatever additional string properties each one may have.

Here is the schema I have so far, how do I fix my schema to have either one or more of the three "sub_props"? I believe I should be utilizing, `anyOf`, but I haven't been able to use it right yet.

**JSON SCHEMA**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "prop1": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "prop2": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "temp_list": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      "prop4": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "prop5": {
        "type": "object",
        "anyOf":[
            {
                "properties": {
        
                    "sub_prop_1": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "additionalProperties": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }, 
                    "sub_prop_2": {
                        "type": "object", 
                        "additionalProperties": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "sub_prop_3": {
                        "type": "object", 
                        "additionalProperties": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
            }


        }}
        ]
      },
      "prop6": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "prop1",
      "prop2",
      "temp_list",
      "prop4",
      "prop5",
      "prop6"
    ]
  }
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/Welcome8",
  "definitions": {
      "Welcome8": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
              "prop1": {
                  "type": "string"
              },
              "prop2": {
                  "type": "string"
              },
              "temp_list": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                      "type": "string"
                  }
              },
              "prop4": {
                  "type": "string"
              },
              "prop5": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/Prop5"
              },
              "prop6": {
                  "type": "string"
              }
          },
          "required": [
              "prop1",
              "prop2",
              "prop4",
              "prop5",
              "prop6",
              "temp_list"
          ],
          "title": "Welcome8"
      },
      "Prop5": {
          "type": "object",
          "minProperties":1,
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
              "sub_prop_1": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/SubProp1"
              },
              "sub_prop_2": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/SubProp2"
              },
              "sub_prop_3": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/SupProp3"
              }
          },
          "anyOf": [ 
              {"required": ["sub_prop_1"]},
              {"required": ["sub_prop_2"]},
              {"required": ["sub_prop_3"]}
          ],
          "title": "Prop5"
      },
      "SubProp1": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": "SubProp1"
      },
      "SubProp2": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": "SubProp2"
      },
      "SupProp3": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": "SupProp3"
      }
  }
}
```